# OpenCV Utils.matToBitmap: Assertion failed AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0 if Bitmap is created with ImageDecoder.createSource

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin

I've this extension function in order to create a Bitmap from a Uri

```
fun Uri.getBitmap(resolver: ContentResolver): Bitmap {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, this)
  } else {
    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(resolver, this)
    return ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
  }
}
```

In `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P`, so when I use `ImageDecoder.createSource` I get this exception:

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: OpenCV(4.1.1) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:38: error: (-215:Assertion failed) AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0
```

While on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P`, so using `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap`, all works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [`ImageDecoder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder) official doc, you can read:

> By default, a Bitmap created by ImageDecoder (including one that is
>   inside a Drawable)
>         will be immutable (i.e. Bitmap#isMutable returns false), and it will typically
>         have Config Bitmap.Config#HARDWARE. Although these properties can be changed
>         with setMutableRequired(true)

So changing the extension function by adding

`setMutableRequired(true)`

In this way:

```
fun Uri.getBitmap(resolver: ContentResolver): Bitmap {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    return MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(resolver, this)
  } else {
    // https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageDecoder
    // CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: OpenCV(4.1.1) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:38: error: (-215:Assertion failed) AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmap, &pixels) >= 0
    /*
      By default, a Bitmap created by ImageDecoder (including one that is inside a Drawable)
      will be immutable (i.e. Bitmap#isMutable returns false), and it will typically
      have Config Bitmap.Config#HARDWARE. Although these properties can be changed
      with setMutableRequired(true)
     */
    val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(resolver, this)
    return ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source) { decoder, _, _ ->
      decoder.isMutableRequired = true
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is gone!